# Set php cookie until browser close with root path access

Tags: php, cookies

I am creating a cookie from this URL "/component/user" in this way:

```
setcookie("isLogged", $options['user']->name);
```

I know it will be removed when the browser close, but doing in this way the cookie will be set up only for the "/component/user" URL instead the whole website, so I did this other one with the intention to make it work for whole the website:

```
setcookie("isLogged", $options['user']->name, "", "/");
```

but the cookie is not created, what I need is a cookie that expire when the browser close and also set it up for whole website. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value = "" [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path = "" [, string $domain = "" [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )

Use `$expire = 0`, as it's a timestamp not a string

```
setcookie("isLogged", $options['user']->name, 0, "/");
```

Comment: Thanks, last question, this same cookie I am trying to remove it with setcookie("isLogged", "", time() - 3600, "/"); do you know why is not being removed here?

Comment: That *should* remove it (ran some tests to make sure). Are you sure you're not setting it again after deleting it?

Comment: yeah, I've tested it too and it should work, so the problem is some other place. Thanks for the help!!